# Batch file log text

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch

I have the following in a batch file:

```
ECHO ---------------- Copy to Test --------- >> "c:\Logs\Posted_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
copy "C:\myfiles\OT*" "c:\OT Test\" >> "C:\Logs\Posted_%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
```

This results in a text file that displays:

```
C:\Myfiles\OT for Dec17.xlsx
        1 file(s) copied.
```

I would like to display not only what file was copied but the target name as well.
Something like this:

```
C:\Myfiles\OT for Dec17.xlsx to c:\OT Test\
```

What do I need to add to my batch file to accomplish this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code properly. As it stands it is impossible to understand.

Comment: What does this have to do with Excel?

Comment: @DavidPostill I thought the same, so I edited the question.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, but the batch file doesn't match the output ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I agree that the copy to test line is missing. Frankly, I do not need that line to understand the question and be able to answer it, which I will do in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `copy` does not have an option to show both the target and destination in its output.

If you really want that in your logfile, there are a few roads you can go. I'll start with the easiest option first, all the way down to the most complicated option last. *(replace >> outputfile.txt with your log file)*

## Echo the path prior to the copy command

The easiest thing is to simply echo the destination to your log.

For example:

```
echo Copying files to C:\OT Test >> outputfile.txt
copy "C:\myfiles\OT*" "c:\OT Test\" >> outputfile.txt
```

## Use another command

Although copy is the easiest to use, its also the most simple copy command available. It is also one of the commands that goes way back. If your script is going to run on recent systems only (windows 8,10, 2012 or 2016), then you will have robocopy on your computer as well, which does support showing the outputpath in its log. robocopy is an advanced copytool though, but the logfile it produces may be all you need anyway.

## Emulate the copy

The next best thing is to use for to cycle through the files first, then in each loop first echo the copy line in the format you like, then on the next line when you actually perform the copy, simply don't output that to your log file.

It will then print to the screen as the script runs, but your logfile will be exactly the way you want it. Given the complex nature of for and my limited time, I can't write you a detailed answer for the for command though. But the first method is likely to be good enough anyway.